# How can I override locale values with custom values in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

In my en.yml locale file (config/locales/en.yml), I have

```
en:
  settings:
    updated: 'Your settings have been updated.'
```

Sometimes, I want to override settings.updated with other text but still use the en locale.

I've tried the following, but settings.updated is not being overwritten:

```
locale_overrides = {"settings"=>{"updated"=>"override text"}}
I18n.backend.store_translations(I18n.locale, {"settings"=>{"updated"=>"override text"}})

p locale_overrides['settings']['updated']
p I18n.t('settings.updated')

assert I18n.t('settings.updated') == locale_overrides['settings']['updated']
```

and the following prints to the console:

```
"override text"
"Your settings have been updated."
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to correctly overwrite locale settings?

**UPDATE**

Looks like this is happening because, as the documentation states,

```
The backend will lazy-load these translations when a translation
is looked up for the first time.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to override a locale value in the first place? I think it's easier and more maintainable to introduce a new key/value and use that for your specific case.

Comment: Where would you introduce the new key/value to? Where would you store it?

Comment: What are the "sometimes" you're talking about?

Comment: Chad, you just add it to your locale file, and use it in stead of the other one. (e.g. "en.settings.updated_alternate")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Chaining with a KeyValue backend:

```
key_value_i18n_backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(locale_overrides_hash)
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(key_value_i18n_backend, I18n.backend)
```